# will_paginate - list alphanumerically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Can anyone recommend how to use the will_paginate gem to paginate a list alphanumerically?

There is this plugin:
http://sermoa.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/rails-alphabetical-pagination/

But I was hoping to get my hands on a method with will_paginate

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add this in my model:

```
default_scope order: 'users.name ASC'
```

Although you could alternatively just do this in your controller:

```
@users = User.page(params[:page]).order(:name)
```

Works with kaminari and, I assume, will_paginate

Comment: PS - you might encounter issues if the values of the field in question are not individually unique. So, it works well if you have something like `validates :name, uniqueness: true` in your model.

Comment: Hey Stephen I am trying to use Kaminari (and tried will_paginate), but nothing seems to appear as rendered html when I load the index  page. An array is created (I can use a puts and see the data in the console/terminal). Any ideas?

Comment: @myarray = MyModel.order(:entry).page(params[:page])

Comment: and in the view: <%= paginate @myarray %>

Comment: Also Stephen will this give me an alphanumeric list/menu rather than numbers?

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're doing it right. Is your code on github? If not could you post your controller and full index view, along with any view helpers that you might have acting on this page? I can take a look at it and see what's up.

Comment: It seems to work - i get the pagination now, and the alphabetical ordering. But I am ultimately trying to get the "menu" to be the alphabet - and a user can click on a letter/number and get just the results of items whose "entry" begins with that letter/number. Sorry I didn't explain that at all very well! Any ideas?